# I am trying to append a dictionary to a JSON file with tkinter

Tags: python, json, tkinter

I am creating a simple login program that will store a user's data in a json file. I am using tkinter for the GUI. But, whenever I hit sign up the data written to the json file in the correct format but is using the string variable from before it is set by the `ttk.Entry()` and outputs just "". I have tried storing each string in a non tkinter variable but didn't seem to fix it. I am very new to python and have been following a tutorial from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/append-to-json-file-using-python/ to try and get it to work mainly because at the bottom of the page it shows an example using a similar json format to mine.

```
def check_pw_match():
    if new_password.get() != confirm_password.get():
        password_match.set("Passwords do not match!")


def update_json(info):
    with open("info.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(info, f, indent=2)
```

```
new_email = StringVar()
new_email.set("")

new_email_label = ttk.Label(right_frame, text="Email:")
new_email_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=3, pady=(10, 3))
new_email_entry = ttk.Entry(right_frame, textvariable=new_email)
new_email_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=3, pady=(10, 3))

new_username = StringVar()
new_username.set("")

new_username_label = ttk.Label(right_frame, text="Username:")
new_username_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=3, pady=3)
new_username_entry = ttk.Entry(right_frame, textvariable=new_username)
new_username_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=3, pady=3)

new_password = StringVar()
new_password.set("")
confirm_password = StringVar()
confirm_password.set("")

new_password_label = ttk.Label(right_frame, text="Password:")
new_password_label.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=3, pady=3)
new_password_entry = ttk.Entry(right_frame, textvariable=new_password, show="*")
new_password_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=3, pady=3)

confirm_password_label = ttk.Label(right_frame, text="Confirm Password:")
confirm_password_label.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=3, pady=(3, 10))
confirm_password_entry = ttk.Entry(right_frame, textvariable=confirm_password, show="*")
confirm_password_entry.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=3, pady=(3, 10))

password_match = StringVar()
password_match.set("---")
password_match_label = ttk.Label(right_frame, textvariable=password_match)
password_match_label.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=(0, 5))

signup_button = ttk.Button(right_frame, text="Create Account", command=lambda: check_pw_match())
signup_button.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=5)

with open("info.json") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    temp = data["users"]

    user_data = {"username": new_username.get(),
                 "email": new_username.get(),
                 "password": new_username.get()
                 }

    temp.append(user_data)

update_json(data)

root.mainloop()
```

Sorry if the last block is long I just wanted you to see where the variables came from.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Try `data['users'].append(user_data)` instead of `temp.append...`

Comment: Also concerning that you are trying to read the Entry fields at the start of the program when nothing will have been entered in to that field. You should probably only add data to the JSON file when the user presses a button. You can create a function which will be called when a button is pressed.